# Update top(N) rows in Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How to update top (N) or limited number of rows in Big Query? I have tried these but none of these worked. What possible ways are there to make it work?

```
UPDATE TOP (20) TABLENAME SET TABLE.COLUMNNAME1 = 'Test' where TABLE.COLUMNNAME2 in ('N', 'C') 

UPDATE TABLENAME SET TABLE.COLUMNNAME1 = 'Test' where TABLE.COLUMNNAME2 in ('N', 'C') LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `UPDATE` statement is part of [Data Manipulation Language (DML) Statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement), make sure that you have **enabled Billing** on your account since DML will not work on a free-tier project.

You can try this query:

```
UPDATE `TABLENAME.replic`
SET TABLE_COLUMNNAME1 = 'Test' 
WHERE TABLE_COLUMNNAME2 IN('N', 'C');
```

Note: `TOP (N)` clause is not implemented in BigQuery.